# bash: child setpgid (5870 to 5870): No such process on docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker, archlinux

```
root@arch:/ 19:27:32 # docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
root@74b77bf42943:/# ls
bash: child setpgid (5870 to 5870): No such process
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr

root@74b77bf42943:/# uname -a 
bash: child setpgid (5935 to 5935): No such process
Linux 74b77bf42943 3.15.3-1-ck #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 2 17:59:56 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix this error "bash: child setpgid (5935 to 5935): No such process"?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the kernel problem , because I use linux-ck kernel,there must be some conflict bettwen docker and the linux-ck kernel, After I change to the normal arch linux kernel ,
everything is good